# sqlite2 autoincrement error

Tags: php, database, sqlite2

I have a problem with sqlite2 (not sqlite3, because I use php).

I tried to create a table with the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE Messaggi (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,content TEXT, date DATETIME DEFAULT (date('now')), owner TEXT, viewed INTEGER DEFAULT (1))
```

But when I launched the script, this output was produced:

```
near "AUTOINCREMENT": syntax error
```

Where's the error?

Ok, I handle it. But now, i get this error:

```
near "(": syntax error
```

, with the query:

```
CREATE TABLE Messaggi (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
Messaggi)+1'),content TEXT, date DATETIME DEFAULT (strftime('%s','now')), owner TEXT, 
viewed INTEGER DEFAULT (1))
```

Comment: If I'm reading the sqlite release notes correctly, the `autoincrement` keyword was added in 3.1.0. http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html

Comment: ok thanks! at least I found the error...

Comment: I doubt you can put a string of SQL as the `DEFAULT` value.

Comment: but in sqlite3 it works fine...